# Fenics: Interior boundary conditions

Tags: python, boundary

I want to combine the Stokes- and the Poisson-equation (Darcy) with the Beaver-Jospeh interface condition. I work in the Unit Square and created two subdomains, one from [0, 0.5] and the other from [0.5, 1]. 
At the interior boundary I want to use the Beaver-Jospeh condition:

```
du/dy(x,0+)=c(u(x,0+)-u_D)
```

where u_D denotes the Darcy-velocity in the porous domain and u(x,0+) the Stokes-velocity in the fluid domain. c is a constant.

Now I don´t know how to create an interior boundary condition. 
I found something like this:

```
facet_domains = FacetFunction('size_t', mesh)
facet_domains.set_all(0)
for f in facets(mesh):
if any(ff.exterior() for ff in facets(f)):
facet_domains[f] = 1

u_in = Constant(-1.0)
bc_in = DirichletBC(V, u_in, facet_domains, 0)
```

But I think i have to use interior facets? 
Can anybody help me how to do this please? I don´t know exactly how to start.

Thanks!